# Google maps V3 dragend listener adds all markers back onto map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map using V3 of the API. It has one marker on it which is draggable and then a load of other markers that are static. I have set up a dragend listener for the draggable marker which calls a function called clear_markers() like so:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker_0, "dragend", function() {
    clear_markers();
});

function clear_markers()
{
  if (markers) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= markers.length; i++ ) {
        if(typeof markers[i] !== "undefined") {
            markers[i].setMap(null);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The reason I start the for loop at 1 and not 0 is that my draggable marker is the first marker so I want to clear all markers from the map except this one.

Here is the problem:

If I call clear_markers(); in any other way it works fine and the markers are removed from the map, so something like this works:

```
$('#mybutton').click(function() {
    clear_markers();
});
```

When you drag and drop the green marker though and it's called from the dragend listener it does not work. The markers do get removed but then they immediately get re added again. I know they do get removed because if I put something in the clear_markers() function just after the for loop that kills the script, the markers get removed. But if the script is allowed to continue they are still there meaning they have been removed and then instantly added back on again.

I'm not calling any other code so it seems like a bug with the api to me. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is a working example showing the problem:

https://tinker.io/64b68/1

Comment: You have not provided enough information to tell what the problem is.  Post a link to the map that shows the problem, obviously there is some other code in the system that is causing the problem.

Comment: I have posted the link, see the link at the bottom of the page that shows all JS and HTML

Comment: He's quite clearly posted a link to tinker.io, showing the problem as clear as it could be shown

Comment: However, I don't see the green_marker on that example (now that you have posted it) [this](http://www.local.propertywishes.com/assets/images/green_marker.png) doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry my fault try it again now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the markerClusterer.  It is adding the markers back in and you aren't using it.

Update:

Since you need to keep it, if you want the markers to not be displayed, you need to remove them from the markerClusterer:

```
 markerCluster.clearMarkers();
```

(but you will need to make it global to use it that way)

Comment: I'm not using it at the moment however in future when the website is populated with a lot more data we will be so that would only be a short term solution really

Comment: Then you need to remove the markers from the markerclusterer or delete the markerclusterer from the map to stop them from being displayed.  It manages the markers for you (which you don't want in this case).

Comment: markerCluster.clearMarkers(); worked a treat thanks so much I was tearing my hair out over this!

Answer (score 1):

Your calling the eventListener the right way, *just not in the right place in your code.* I added a couple of alerts in your eventListener to see what was going on and if you see on the second alert, the markers are actually cleared - but once the alert box is closed the markers reappear. Try it yourself:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker_0, "dragend", function() {
    alert("before calling clear_markers()");
    clear_markers();
    alert("markers should be cleared");
});
```

*This means that once javascript runs into your "dragend" event listener, it will execute the code inside - but then it will go through the rest of the code as well and hence the markers get populated on the map again. You can fix this issue by adding your event listener to the end of your `initialize()` function after `var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, clusterOptions);`.*

**text in italics is the wrong explanation, refer to the response below for the correct solution**

/---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------/

Disregarding my previous answer, allow me to re-edit. Again, you are calling the eventListener the right way. You will just need to add the following piece of code in the listener function to make sure the markers do not show up.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker_0, "dragend", function() {
    clear_markers();
    markerCluster.setMap(null);
});
```

It seems initiating the markerCluster overrides your clear function on the markers. So you will also need to clear the markerCluster from your map as well. Apologies for misguiding you in my previous response, markerCluster is a new concept to me as well.

Comment: In the future, if you have any eventListeners that trigger "clearing" functionality - add it to the end of your code.

Comment: It is only a superficial fix, zooming in or out will redraw the markers again. Resetting the clusterer's markers seems to be necessary. I suspect that instantiating the marker clusterer changes something in the listeners and overrides the `clear_markers`. I don't think "the rest of the code" is run again, because, using the original code, I placed an alert right before the `new MarkerClusterer` line and the alert does not pop up twice.

Comment: You're right, it appears initiating the `MarkerCluster` does do some funny overriding. However, similar the markers setting markerCluster on the map to null will clear the markers for good `markerCluster.setMap(null);`. I will edit my answer accordingly, thank you for the catch @MaryAnne